# Code samples for future employers

Tags: interviewing, career-development, career-switch

I'm a new professional software developer and I have a rather odd situation.

My job, while being technical, is not in a tradional software environment. I am the sole developer who was hired to slowly take over a senior developer as he is edged out since he decided to take another job.

I accepted my current job after I submitted a code sample, my senior project in school, and they extended an offer. I do not plan on leaving, as I love the atmosphere and my co-workers, but if I ever do want to leave or if something happens and I get let go, should I have code samples for future employers since my current job isn't easily compared with bigger companies and the heirarchy they may use? I.e. Junior Dev, Dev, Senior Dev, etc..

I classify myself as a Junior Software Developer, if that matters to anyone.

Comment: It can't hurt to have samples, some employers want them, others don't, but the more arrows to your bow the better.

Comment: Get involved in an Open Source

Comment: I didn't even think of that @Paparazzi. Great idea.

Comment: @Micheal: You *have* to get involved in open source, or have a side-project. You can't just go giving out code samples of your employers code (you don't own it) to other people without permission.

Comment: Related thread: [Potential employer asks for code sample](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76935/potential-employer-asks-for-code-sample)

Comment: As a caution.  NEVER give out code samples from your previous employers, in case this didn't really cross your mind.  You **WILL BE SUED**.

Comment: @Nelson makes a good point, in case someone else reading this did not know this. In my case, I've actually signed some NDA's so I definitely could be sued if I were to do that.

Comment: Even if you didn't sign NDAs, code you produce have assumed IP rights of the company because you are producing said code under employment.  Code created under employment is the company's, not yours.  I forgot the specific term at the moment, but I've read about it couple times here.

Comment: @Nelson that is great info. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: It's considered good practice to have some "code samples" usually in form of open source contributions or private projects on github. You can't use code from your place of employment, just don't ever do that. Being involved in opensource can greatly benefit you in more than one way and it benefit every one who uses software you have contributed to. It's a win/win thing.

Comment: While @Nelson makes a good point, you **can** use samples from an employer if you gut or rewrite the proprietary information and make it generic.  Most of this can be done by renaming variables and changing the procedures slightly.

Comment: @RoughTomato How can you use an open source contribution as a code sample? For example, say I contributed some bug fixes to Firefox. How are you going to submit that as a "code sample"?

Comment: @Brandin I usually attach link to my profile in my CV. So people involved in recruitment can access everything they need. In past I haven't been attaching my profile and I was asked a lot about "providing some example code". There is information on github about your contribution, bug fixes, issues posted. Although I have had situation where recruiters didn't even checked my account, just mentioned it in the interview and asked what kind of projects I was involved in open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! You should have code samples (but not of code you wrote at work unless you have permission in writing from your employer - that code is theirs, not yours) regardless of anything unusual about your current job, it can't hurt you to have them handy and might help a lot.

> since my current job isn't easily compared with bigger companies and the hierarchy they may use? I.e. Junior Dev, Dev, Senior Dev, etc..

I think specific titles on a resume are less interesting than details about what you did, so you shouldn't worry too much about that. Everyone who has been in the industry long enough to be reviewing resumes as part of their job has seen bad developers with senior titles and great ones with junior titles. Just describe what you did on your resume and you'll be fine.

Comment: Code samples are always good... To Mel's point, you can't give out your company's property, unless, of course, you convince them to open-source some of the work, in which case you get the benefit of building your portfolio while at work!