# Code sample for embedded software developer application?

Tags: applications, code

Unexpectedly, I've the chance for a dream job as an embedded software developer. The application requires a code sample to be included with the CV. I have a very good experience in C. But unfortunately for different reasons, I don't have ready samples to be sent.

What can I write in, say, 5 hours or less that can be considered a good sample. I mean what ideas or small projects that can do the job? I'm really lost and don't want to miss the chance because of this.

I found ideas for projects for general programmer (i.e., not embedded) but didn't find ideas for code samples for embedded software position.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of code sample? There must be a requirement, otherwise you could send a hello world program. Even if they require something, what sense is in sending it with your cv? you could submit code from any origins.

Comment: You should probably pick something involving tools, libraries or concepts you have a lot of experience with (which we wouldn't be able to advise you on), otherwise you'll probably spend a large portion of the time just getting familiar with those things.

Comment: Related: [What are employers looking for when they ask to see sample code during the hiring process for a programmer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1309)

Answer (score 7):

Write a very simple application that pulls in weather data from various APIs.

Write a very simple application that uses OpenSSL and other libraries for secure communication.

Write a very simple application that receives input from an Arduino, calls out to a central API, and determines if the correct value has been entered.

If you demonstrate your ability to use an API, a mind for security, and your ability to use existing libraries, you'll give a good showing.

Whether you can do that in 5 hours ... that's up to you.  I wouldn't be able to do that.  But my C isn't as good as it used to be.

Comment: To paraphrase a famous quote from software ..  it often takes me a week to write one line of code, and it's usually wrong.  The idea of "writing code" in five hours is hilarious.  You might as well "prove you're a! novelist!" in "five hours".   OP's best bet, with this absurd marketing gimmick, is to out-gimmick them.

Answer (score -8):

I feel for you.

Let's go for the smart ass, trendy answer;

> Can you combine something very simple with say the astounding PubNub. https://www.pubnub.com

## *In this way you can instantly hit all the bullshit hot keywords of the day, doing almost nothing.*

There's nothing hotter than IoT and, hell, if you can realistically work towards embedded + IoT in *five hours*, we'd hire you.

Just have two .. lights or something that stay in sync, anywhere on Earth, via the

## gasp "cloud"

and I bet you're In like Flynn.  Good luck, really !